# How can I allow the user to be able to input something by typing in the keyboard infinitely using the Scanner feature?

Tags: java, bluej

In my code, I was able to use the scanner feature to prompt the user to type a piece of text, however, I was only able to make it so the user can type once. To type again I would have to close the terminal, and open it again, how can I make it so that I can just type infinitely so that I wouldn't have to close it and reopen it every time in order to type again?
For context, this is my code, it is about a ticket machine which displays certain data, like the name of the person, the price, the total balance, etc. Currently I am doing the places. This means that I want the user to type any city in England, and a price would appear. But as I said, the user can only jarringly type one thing at a time, when they should be able to type without any limit.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class TicketMachine
{
    
    private int price;
    
    private int balance;
    
    private int total;
    /**
     * Create a machine that issues tickets of the given price.
     */
    public TicketMachine(int cost)
    {
        price = cost;
        balance = 0;
        total = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @Return The price of a ticket.
     */
    public int getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * Return The amount of money already inserted for the
     * next ticket.
     */
    public int getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    /**
     * Receive an amount of money from a customer.
     * Check that the amount is sensible.
     */
    public void insertMoney(int amount)
    {
        if(amount > 0) {
            balance = balance + amount;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Use a positive amount rather than: " +
                amount);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print a ticket if enough money has been inserted, and
     * reduce the current balance by the ticket price. Print
     * an error message if more money is required.
     */
    public void printTicket()
    {
        if(balance >= price) {
            // Simulate the printing of a ticket.
            System.out.println("HERE IS YOUR TICKET");

            System.out.println("# Ticket");
            System.out.println("# " + price + " cents.");
            System.out.println("You have" + balance + "left");

            // Update the total collected with the price.
            total = total + price;
            // Reduce the balance by the price.
            balance = balance - price;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You must insert at least: " +
                (price - balance) + " more cents.");

        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the money in the balance.
     * The balance is cleared.
     */
    public int refundBalance()
    {
        int amountToRefund;
        amountToRefund = balance;
        balance = 0;
        return amountToRefund;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
       
     
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = myScanner.nextLine();
      
        
        
        
        if( answer.equals("London") )
        {
            System.out.println("£15");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Manchester") )
        {
            System.out.println("£20");
        }

        if( answer.equals("Brighton") )
        {
            System.out.println("£25");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Cornwall") )
        {
            System.out.println("£30");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Crystal Palace") )
        {
            System.out.println("£35");
        }

        if( answer.equals("Chealsea") )
        {
            System.out.println("£40");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Birmingham") )
        {
            System.out.println("£45");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Liverpool") )
        {
            System.out.println("£50");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Bristol") )
        {
            System.out.println("£55");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Leister") )
        {
            System.out.println("£60");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Newcastle") )
        {
            System.out.println("£65");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Cambridge") )
        {
            System.out.println("£70");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Bradford") )
        {
            System.out.println("£75");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Leeds") )
        {
            System.out.println("£80");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Oxford") )
        {
            System.out.println("£85");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Nottingham") )
        {
            System.out.println("£90");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Peterborough") )
        {
            System.out.println("£95");
        }
        if( answer.equals("Sheffield") )
        {
            System.out.println("£100");
        }
   
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile so we can't run it and reproduce your problem, which makes it hard to debug. To get proper answers reduce your code to [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), in short *minimal* (without unrelated parts) but *complete* (so we wouldn't need to write anything more) example which allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: But aside from that, if I remember correctly BlueJ was (or still is) facing problem with properly handling input stream (represented by System.in) which may cause problems with Scanner. Maybe before you do anything else, check if your real code runs fine by manually compiling and running it via console, or some other IDE.

Comment: Pshemo, remove the "for (" and the code will compile.

Comment: Use [edit] option and correct that in your example.

Comment: Thanks, one more thing. I need to make it so after I type a city and a price shows up, the text "PLEASE PAY NOW" appears, and if I type the exact price, it says "THANK YOU, HAVE A NICE DAY", if I type a number smaller than the price, it tells me how much money I am short of, if I type a number larger than the price, it tells me how much change I have.

Comment: New problems deserve their own questions. Also include description of problem which you faced while writing your code.

Comment: BTW your example contains things which can be shortened (like do we really need to see all those ifs which handle so many cities, probably 2-3 of them would be enough to show the idea). To ask better questions (and increase chances of getting good answers) please familiarize yourself with [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a while true or a infinite loop isn't a good practice. You can use a do-while and check a flag (e.g. "exit") to close the program e.g.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class TicketMachine {

     private int price;

     private int balance;

     private int total;

     /**
      * Create a machine that issues tickets of the given price.
      */
     public TicketMachine(int cost) {
          price = cost;
          balance = 0;
          total = 0;
     }

     /**
      * @Return The price of a ticket.
      */
     public int getPrice() {
          return price;
     }

     /**
      * Return The amount of money already inserted for the next ticket.
      */
     public int getBalance() {
          return balance;
     }

     /**
      * Receive an amount of money from a customer. Check that the amount is sensible.
      */
     public void insertMoney(int amount) {
          if (amount > 0) {
               balance = balance + amount;
          } else {
               System.out.println("Use a positive amount rather than: "
                       + amount);
          }
     }

     /**
      * Print a ticket if enough money has been inserted, and reduce the current balance by the
      * ticket price. Print an error message if more money is required.
      */
     public void printTicket() {
          if (balance >= price) {
               // Simulate the printing of a ticket.
               System.out.println("HERE IS YOUR TICKET");

               System.out.println("# Ticket");
               System.out.println("# " + price + " cents.");
               System.out.println("You have" + balance + "left");

               // Update the total collected with the price.
               total = total + price;
               // Reduce the balance by the price.
               balance = balance - price;
          } else {
               System.out.println("You must insert at least: "
                       + (price - balance) + " more cents.");

          }
     }

     /**
      * Return the money in the balance. The balance is cleared.
      */
     public int refundBalance() {
          int amountToRefund;
          amountToRefund = balance;
          balance = 0;
          return amountToRefund;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

          String answer = "";

          do {

               System.out.println("Enter your city, please:");
               answer = myScanner.nextLine();

               if (answer.equals("London")) {
                    System.out.println("£15");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Manchester")) {
                    System.out.println("£20");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Brighton")) {
                    System.out.println("£25");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Cornwall")) {
                    System.out.println("£30");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Crystal Palace")) {
                    System.out.println("£35");
               }

               else if (answer.equals("Chealsea")) {
                    System.out.println("£40");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Birmingham")) {
                    System.out.println("£45");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Liverpool")) {
                    System.out.println("£50");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Bristol")) {
                    System.out.println("£55");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Leister")) {
                    System.out.println("£60");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Newcastle")) {
                    System.out.println("£65");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Cambridge")) {
                    System.out.println("£70");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Bradford")) {
                    System.out.println("£75");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Leeds")) {
                    System.out.println("£80");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Oxford")) {
                    System.out.println("£85");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Nottingham")) {
                    System.out.println("£90");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Peterborough")) {
                    System.out.println("£95");
               }
               else if (answer.equals("Sheffield")) {
                    System.out.println("£100");
               }else { 
                    System.out.println("ERROR: INVALID INPUT");
              }

          } while (answer != "exit");

     }
}
```

PS use a switch case instead of if(){} e.g

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class TicketMachine {

     private int price;

     private int balance;

     private int total;

     /**
      * Create a machine that issues tickets of the given price.
      */
     public TicketMachine(int cost) {
          price = cost;
          balance = 0;
          total = 0;
     }

     /**
      * @Return The price of a ticket.
      */
     public int getPrice() {
          return price;
     }

     /**
      * Return The amount of money already inserted for the next ticket.
      */
     public int getBalance() {
          return balance;
     }

     /**
      * Receive an amount of money from a customer. Check that the amount is sensible.
      */
     public void insertMoney(int amount) {
          if (amount > 0) {
               balance = balance + amount;
          } else {
               System.out.println("Use a positive amount rather than: "
                       + amount);
          }
     }

     /**
      * Print a ticket if enough money has been inserted, and reduce the current balance by the
      * ticket price. Print an error message if more money is required.
      */
     public void printTicket() {
          if (balance >= price) {
               // Simulate the printing of a ticket.
               System.out.println("HERE IS YOUR TICKET");

               System.out.println("# Ticket");
               System.out.println("# " + price + " cents.");
               System.out.println("You have" + balance + "left");

               // Update the total collected with the price.
               total = total + price;
               // Reduce the balance by the price.
               balance = balance - price;
          } else {
               System.out.println("You must insert at least: "
                       + (price - balance) + " more cents.");

          }
     }

     /**
      * Return the money in the balance. The balance is cleared.
      */
     public int refundBalance() {
          int amountToRefund;
          amountToRefund = balance;
          balance = 0;
          return amountToRefund;
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

          String answer = "";

          do {

               System.out.println("Enter your city, please:");
               answer = myScanner.nextLine();

               switch (answer) {
                    case "London":
                         System.out.println("£15");
                         break;
                    case "Manchester":
                         System.out.println("£20");
                         break;
                    case "Brighton":
                         System.out.println("£25");
                         break;
                    case "Cornwall":
                         System.out.println("£30");
                         break;
                    case "Crystal Palace":
                         System.out.println("£35");
                         break;
                    case "Chealsea":
                         System.out.println("£40");
                         break;
                    case "Birmingham":
                         System.out.println("£45");
                         break;
                    case "Liverpool":
                         System.out.println("£50");
                         break;
                    case "Bristol":
                         System.out.println("£55");
                         break;
                    case "Leister":
                         System.out.println("£20");
                         break;
                    case "Newcastle":
                         System.out.println("£65");
                         break;
                    case "Cambridge":
                         System.out.println("£70");
                         break;
                    case "Bradford":
                         System.out.println("£75");
                         break;
                    case "Leeds":
                         System.out.println("£80");
                         break;
                    case "Oxford":
                         System.out.println("£85");
                         break;
                    case "Nottingham":
                         System.out.println("£90");
                         break;
                    case "Peterborough":
                         System.out.println("£95");
                         break;
                    case "Sheffield":
                         System.out.println("£100");
                         break;
                    default:
                         System.out.println("ERROR: INVALID INPUT");
                         break;
               }

          } while (answer != "exit");

     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much sir, just tried it , and it works. There is one more thing however. I also need to make it so if I type anything other than the cities I have listed it would type, "ERROR: INVALID INPUT" This is something I've been stuck on.

Comment: If you use the switch case solution just edit the default: case (im going to edit the answer), please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks, it works. One more thing. I need to make it so after I type a city and a price shows up, the text "PLEASE PAY NOW" appears, and if I type the exact price, it says "THANK YOU, HAVE A NICE DAY", if I type a number smaller than the price, it tells me how much money I am short of, if I type a number larger than the price, it tells me how much change I have.